# keydown event not working the same as button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I press the search button the sendTitle() function works perfectly, but when I press the enter key (keyCode == 13), the sendTitle() function throws the catch error response (alert cannot connect) every time. I am wondering if anyone knows why it does not work when I press enter on the form input. I put my code in a jsFiddle here. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/k_g_j/yzcomd7s/4/

```js
var sendTitle = function() {
  var title = $("input[name='movie-search-title']").val();
  console.log(title)
  getMovie(title)
  getQuotes(title)
}
$("input[name='movie-search-title']").keydown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    sendTitle();
  }
})
// movie search 
var getMovie = function(title) {
  $("#main").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#search-form").trigger("reset");
  //format the OMDB api url 
  var apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${title}&plot=full&apikey=836f8b0`
  //make a request to the url 
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
      // request was successful 
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(function(movieData) {
          console.log(movieData)
          showMovie(movieData)
        });
      } else {
        alert("Error: title not found!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert("Unable to connect to cine score app");
    });
};
var getQuotes = function(title) {
  var title = title.replaceAll(" ", "_")
  const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": `https://movie-and-tv-shows-quotes.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/from/${title}`,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "movie-and-tv-shows-quotes.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "229d984177msh18d191b1335378fp137dcejsn7c92ab2acfaf"
    }
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(quoteData) {
      console.log(quoteData);
      showQuotes(quoteData)
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      //Ajax request failed.
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
      console.log(`Error - ${errorMessage}`);
      $("#movie-quotes").empty();
    });
}

var showMovie = function(movieData) {
  $("#movie-title").text(movieData.Title)
  $("#year-rating").text(`${movieData.Year}, ${movieData.Rated}`)
  $("#genre").text(`${movieData.Genre}`)
  $("#synopsis").text(movieData.Plot)
  $("#poster").attr("src", movieData.Poster);
  $("#cast-list").text(`Main Cast: ${movieData.Actors}`)
  $("#director").text(`Director: ${movieData.Director}`)
  $("#writer").text(`Writer(s): ${movieData.Writer}`)
  $("#imdb-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[0].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[0].Value}`)
  $("#tomatoes-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[1].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[1].Value}`)
  $("#metacritic-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[2].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[2].Value}`)
  var tomatoesRate = (movieData.Ratings[1].Value).replace("%", "")
  parseInt(tomatoesRate)
  if (tomatoesRate <= 60) {
    $("#tomatoes-rate").attr("src", "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/351-3516739_cherry-tomato-clipart-tomatoe-rotten-tomatoes-icon-png.png")
  } else if (tomatoesRate >= 60) {
    $("#tomatoes-rate").attr("src", "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/50-503981_rotten-tomatoes-fresh-logo.png")
  }
}
var showQuotes = function(quoteData) {
  $("#movie-quotes-heading").text("Movie Quotes")
  quoteData.forEach(quoteItem => {
    var carouselItem = document.createElement("div")
    $(carouselItem).html(`<h4 class='quote'>"${quoteItem.quote}"<br><br><span class='quote-character'>-${quoteItem.character}</span></h4><br>`)
    $(carouselItem).appendTo("#quote-carousel");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #40376E;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
}

.bg-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.logo-small {
  color: #40376E;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  color: #40376E;
  font-size: 200px;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#tomatoes-rate {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  color: #40376E;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #40376E;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #40376E;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 70px 0;
}

.item span {
  font-style: normal;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #40376E;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.panel-footer .btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #40376E;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: #40376E;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #40376E !important;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-footer {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.panel-footer h4 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-footer .btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #40376E;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #40376E;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #40376E !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #40376E;
}

.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Cine Score</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" </head>

  <body id="mainPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

    <!-- Navigation Menu -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Cine Score</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#past-searches">Past Searches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favorite-soundtracks">Favorite Soundtracks</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Movie Search Jumbotron -->
    <div id="movie-search" class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Search for a movie!</h1>
      <form id="search-form">
        <input name="movie-search-title" type="text" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="movie title" />
        <button id="searchBtn" type='button' class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendTitle()">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <main id="main" class=hidden>
      <!-- Container (main movie info) -->
      <div id="movie-info" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2 id="movie-title"></h2><br>
            <h4 id="year-rating"></h4>
            <h4 id="genre"></h4><br>
            <p id="synopsis"></p>
            <br><button id="get-soundtrack" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get the soundtrack</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span id="movie-poster">
        <img id="poster" src="" />
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (cast) -->
      <div id="cast" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="cast-icon" class="col-sm-4">
            <span>
        <img  src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3873/3873990.png" />
      </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2>Cast</h2><br>
            <h4 id="cast-list"></h4><br>
            <p id="director">
            </p>
            <p id="writer">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Score Section) -->
      <div id="score" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span id="rating-img">
        <img id="tomatoes-rate" src=""/>
      </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
            <h2>SCORE</h2><br>
            <h4 id="imdb-rate"></h4><br>
            <h4 id="tomatoes-rate"></h4><br>
            <h4 id="metacritic-rate"></h4><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Sountrack Section) -->
      <div id="soundtrack" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
        <h2>Sountrack</h2><br>
        <h4 id="movie-title-soundtrack">Movie Soundtrack</h4>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <p>Soundtrack Image</p>
          <p>List of songs</p>
          <button id="save-to-favorites" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Save to favorites!</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Movie Quotes Section)-->
      <div id="movie-quotes" class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h2 id="movie-quotes-heading"></h2>
        <div id="quoteCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div id="quote-carousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <a href="#mainPage" title="To Top">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"> Top </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a small change;

First it's `e.preventDefault()` not `e.preventDefault`

Second, move it into the if statement like:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sendTitle();
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var sendTitle = function() {
  var title = $("input[name='movie-search-title']").val();
  console.log(title)
  getMovie(title)
  getQuotes(title)
}
$("input[name='movie-search-title']").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendTitle();
  }
})
// movie search 
var getMovie = function(title) {
  $("#main").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#search-form").trigger("reset");
  //format the OMDB api url 
  var apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${title}&plot=full&apikey=836f8b0`
  //make a request to the url 
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
      // request was successful 
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(function(movieData) {
          console.log(movieData)
          showMovie(movieData)
        });
      } else {
        alert("Error: title not found!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert("Unable to connect to cine score app");
    });
};
var getQuotes = function(title) {
  var title = title.replaceAll(" ", "_")
  const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": `https://movie-and-tv-shows-quotes.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/from/${title}`,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "movie-and-tv-shows-quotes.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "229d984177msh18d191b1335378fp137dcejsn7c92ab2acfaf"
    }
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(quoteData) {
      console.log(quoteData);
      showQuotes(quoteData)
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      //Ajax request failed.
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
      console.log(`Error - ${errorMessage}`);
      $("#movie-quotes").empty();
    });
}

var showMovie = function(movieData) {
  $("#movie-title").text(movieData.Title)
  $("#year-rating").text(`${movieData.Year}, ${movieData.Rated}`)
  $("#genre").text(`${movieData.Genre}`)
  $("#synopsis").text(movieData.Plot)
  $("#poster").attr("src", movieData.Poster);
  $("#cast-list").text(`Main Cast: ${movieData.Actors}`)
  $("#director").text(`Director: ${movieData.Director}`)
  $("#writer").text(`Writer(s): ${movieData.Writer}`)
  $("#imdb-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[0].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[0].Value}`)
  $("#tomatoes-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[1].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[1].Value}`)
  $("#metacritic-rate").text(`${movieData.Ratings[2].Source} - ${movieData.Ratings[2].Value}`)
  var tomatoesRate = (movieData.Ratings[1].Value).replace("%", "")
  parseInt(tomatoesRate)
  if (tomatoesRate <= 60) {
    $("#tomatoes-rate").attr("src", "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/351-3516739_cherry-tomato-clipart-tomatoe-rotten-tomatoes-icon-png.png")
  } else if (tomatoesRate >= 60) {
    $("#tomatoes-rate").attr("src", "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/50-503981_rotten-tomatoes-fresh-logo.png")
  }
}
var showQuotes = function(quoteData) {
  $("#movie-quotes-heading").text("Movie Quotes")
  quoteData.forEach(quoteItem => {
    var carouselItem = document.createElement("div")
    $(carouselItem).html(`<h4 class='quote'>"${quoteItem.quote}"<br><br><span class='quote-character'>-${quoteItem.character}</span></h4><br>`)
    $(carouselItem).appendTo("#quote-carousel");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #40376E;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#search-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
}

.bg-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.logo-small {
  color: #40376E;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  color: #40376E;
  font-size: 200px;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#tomatoes-rate {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  color: #40376E;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #40376E;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #40376E;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 70px 0;
}

.item span {
  font-style: normal;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #40376E;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.panel-footer .btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #40376E;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: #40376E;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #40376E !important;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-footer {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.panel-footer h4 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-footer .btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #40376E;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #40376E;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #40376E !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #40376E;
}

.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Cine Score</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" </head>

  <body id="mainPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

    <!-- Navigation Menu -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Cine Score</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#past-searches">Past Searches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favorite-soundtracks">Favorite Soundtracks</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Movie Search Jumbotron -->
    <div id="movie-search" class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Search for a movie!</h1>
      <form id="search-form">
        <input name="movie-search-title" type="text" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="movie title" />
        <button id="searchBtn" type='button' class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendTitle()">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <main id="main" class=hidden>
      <!-- Container (main movie info) -->
      <div id="movie-info" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2 id="movie-title"></h2><br>
            <h4 id="year-rating"></h4>
            <h4 id="genre"></h4><br>
            <p id="synopsis"></p>
            <br><button id="get-soundtrack" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get the soundtrack</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span id="movie-poster">
        <img id="poster" src="" />
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (cast) -->
      <div id="cast" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="cast-icon" class="col-sm-4">
            <span>
        <img  src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3873/3873990.png" />
      </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2>Cast</h2><br>
            <h4 id="cast-list"></h4><br>
            <p id="director">
            </p>
            <p id="writer">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Score Section) -->
      <div id="score" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span id="rating-img">
        <img id="tomatoes-rate" src=""/>
      </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
            <h2>SCORE</h2><br>
            <h4 id="imdb-rate"></h4><br>
            <h4 id="tomatoes-rate"></h4><br>
            <h4 id="metacritic-rate"></h4><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Sountrack Section) -->
      <div id="soundtrack" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
        <h2>Sountrack</h2><br>
        <h4 id="movie-title-soundtrack">Movie Soundtrack</h4>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <p>Soundtrack Image</p>
          <p>List of songs</p>
          <button id="save-to-favorites" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Save to favorites!</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container (Movie Quotes Section)-->
      <div id="movie-quotes" class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h2 id="movie-quotes-heading"></h2>
        <div id="quoteCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div id="quote-carousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <a href="#mainPage" title="To Top">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"> Top </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I believe you can also in the HTML alter the submit form to `<form id="search-form" onSubmit="return false;">`. Is this considered bad practise?

Comment: @darclander Depends, I would believe it would be better practise not to use a <form> if no need of it. In this case there is no need of a form.